# How to create a base template and use it to wrap other templates in Ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I couldn't find anything about this. basically i want to create a base template, with all the `head` tag and `container` in body or menu, etc... so that other templates can extend it.

how would i achieve this with Ionic framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have phrased your question leads one to think you have not quite understood how Ionic works...

A typical Ionic app has only **one** index.html file with a `<head>`. The rest of the .html files are just content templates to be rendered as the content of that page. So you don't need the "base template" you are asking about, that is all taken care of by Ionic, from the index.html.

I would suggest reading and following http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html

Comment: Thank you. I just started with Ionic few days back while looking for a framework.